# Failed to register a ServiceWorker. The script resource is behind a redirect, which is disallowed

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, service-worker, aws-amplify, flutter-web

I wanna make a flutter web app and deploy it to AWS.
After researching it looks like using AWS Amplify is the easiest way so I try it, however after I successfully deploy it, it only shows a white screen with this showing on the log after I inspect:

[image: Console Log]

However the web app show up just fine on my GitHub page and Codemagic, you can see it on rezyfr.github.io and fl-blog.codemagic.app. And here is my amplify yaml file:

[image: amplify yaml]

Is anyone ever experience this and found the solution? Or anyone have a better way to deploy flutter web on AWS?